# Regex - convert the string to camel caps by `dot`

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a solution to convert my string to `camelcaps` by the `dot` it contains.

here is my string: `'sender.state'`

I am expecting the result as : `'senderState'`;

I tried this: `'sender.state'.replace(/\./g, '');` it removes the `.` but how to handle the `camel caps` stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function to `.replace()`:

```
'sender.state'.replace(/\.([a-z])/g, (match, letter) => letter.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: this is nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Without `regex` - this might help :

```
var str = "bad.unicron";
var temp = str.split(".");
return temp[0]+temp[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp[1].slice(1);
```

I'll try to come up with `regex`